# Jquery get data for divs with attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of divs which have a id value of `#result-1, #result-2` etc. So the divs have a prefix number at the end of them. I am getting the value of how many list items that divs has by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var colorCount = $('#result-1 .item-result ul li');

    if (colorCount.length > 0)  {
       $('.test').html(colorCount.length + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
    }
    else {
       $('.test').hide();
    }
});
```

So at the moment I am targeting the first element only, How would I target the attribute based on the id or data-srch-position. The div has the following attributes:

```
<div id="result-1" class="search-item" data-srch-position="1" style="width: 100%;">
```

So I would want to target either the `div_id` or the `data-srch-position="1"`

So the prefix number changes i.e id result-2 and data-srch-position="2" etc

The `.test` class is simply `<div class='test'></div>` where the `colorCount.length` gets binded to for display.

[JS Fiddle link:](https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/k8ar0bc6/1/)

Comment: It's not clear what the full logic is; is there a `.test` element for each `#result-N`? It seems that using common classes and DRY logic instead of incremental `id` would be a far better approach here.

Comment: I have updated the question with the structure

Comment: Where's the `.test` element's HTML? How does it relate to each `#result-N`?

Comment: How much `%` is `%%` and is that inline style needed for your question. PS: DIVs are block-level by default, so most probably you don't even need that style. Also, what if you have multiple `.test` elements? And what's that element at all?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan apologies typo

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

First of `.test` will target every single `.test` element you have in the page, so in order to print a distinct and specific value it's not ideal since it will always be overwritten with the latest number found (...well unless that's your intent which is currently unclear)

- To read the data value you simple access the `.data()`
- Target distinct `.test` elements using `.find()` (if those are children elements)

```js
$('[data-srch-position]').each((i, el) => {
  const n = $(el).data('srch-position');
  $(el).find('.test').text(n);
});
```

```html
<div data-srch-position="3">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="7">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="1">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="9">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="42">What is <span class="test"></span> anyways...</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

or you could go the other way around, target each child `.test` and than search the parent `data-*` attribute value using `.closest('parent or self selector')`:

```js
$('.test').each((i, el) => {
  const n = $(el).closest('[data-srch-position]').data('srch-position');
  $(el).text(n);
});
```

```html
<div data-srch-position="3">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="7">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="1">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="9">My srch: <span class="test"></span></div>
<div data-srch-position="42">What is <span class="test"></span> anyways...</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

Given your jsFiddle example, you could move the `data-*` selector into the desired elements instead and use a selector as target:

```js
$('[data-count-li]').each(function() {
  const selector = $(this).data('count-li'); // Get the ID selector
  const $LI = $(selector).find('li');        // Find the selector's LI elements
  const LI_total = $LI.length;               // How many LI elements
  
  if(LI_total) { // If higher than 0
    $(this).show().text(`FOUND: ${LI_total} LI ELEMENTS`); // SHOW AND PRINT NUMBER
  }
});
```

```css
[data-count-li] {
  display: none;  /* HIDE BY DEFAULT (SHOW USING JS) */
}
```

```html
<div id="result-item-1" class="search">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-count-li="#result-item-1">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-2" class="search">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-count-li="#result-item-2">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-3" class="search">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-count-li="#result-item-3">Test</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Roko. Minimal example: here https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/k8ar0bc6/1/

Comment: Why have you used `i, el`?

Comment: @Sole DOCS: https://api.jquery.com/each/ `i` is **index** and `el` is the currently iterating `Element`. I could've used `$(this)` instead of `$(el)` but since I user Arrow Function syntax the `this` would not be the Element context but `Window` eventually.

Comment: @Sole in your jsFiddle, where is/are that/those `.test` Element/s? Even after looking your jsFiddle example I'm still not exactly sure what you're after. What's the expected result? What should happen?

Comment: In the JSFiddle to make it easier to understand I renamed it `numberOfColours` as this may of caused confusion.

Comment: as you can see on the JS fiddle, the colors are simple to count the amount of list elements in the attribute value

Comment: @Sole see if my answer edit (and the last snippet) helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I believe you want to happen.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colorCount = $('.search-item[data-srch-position]');

    $(colorCount).each(function(i, value){
        ($(this).text().length > 0) ? console.log('true') : console.log('false');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-1" class="search-item multiple " data-srch-position="1" style="width: 100%%;">test1</div>
<div id="result-2" class="search-item multiple " data-srch-position="1" style="width: 100%%;">test2</div>
<div id="result-3" class="search-item multiple " data-srch-position="1" style="width: 100%%;"></div>
```

Comment: `$()` is always a jQuery object - therefore you'll never get `console.log('false')`